# Transform json array of objects

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json with "proceds" and "teams".

Id´like to transform it grouping it by team.

Next, I show a snippet what I want achieve.

How can I do it?

```
dados:{
proceds:[
 {id:'1', proc:'11', teams:[{team_id:1},{team_id:2}]},
 {id:'2', proc:'12', teams:[{team_id:1},{team_id:3}]},
 {id:'3', proc:'13', teams:[{team_id:2},{team_id:3}]},
]
}
```

I´d like to transform "dados" to:

```
dados:{
 teams:[
  {team_id:1, proceds:[{id:'1', proc:'11'},{id:'2', proc:'12'}],
  {team_id:2, proceds:[{id:'1', proc:'11'},{id:'3', proc:'13'}]
  {team_id:3, proceds:[{id:'2', proc:'12'},{id:'3', proc:'13'}]
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an object lookup for each team id and then generate the result using `Object.entries` and `array#map`.

```js
const data = [ {id:'1', proc:'11', teams:[{team_id:1},{team_id:2}]}, {id:'2', proc:'12', teams:[{team_id:1},{team_id:3}]}, {id:'3', proc:'13', teams:[{team_id:2},{team_id:3}]}, ],
    result = Object.entries(data.reduce((r, o) => {
      o.teams.forEach(({ team_id }) => {
        r[team_id] = r[team_id] || [];
        r[team_id].push({ id: o.id, proc: o.proc });
      });
      return r;
    }, {})).map(([team_id, proceds]) => ({ team_id, proceds }));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const dados = {
    proceds:[
     {id:'1', proc:'11', teams:[{team_id:1},{team_id:2}]},
     {id:'2', proc:'12', teams:[{team_id:1},{team_id:3}]},
     {id:'3', proc:'13', teams:[{team_id:2},{team_id:3}]},
    ]
}

function transform(object) {
    object.teams = object.proceds.map((obj) => ({
        team_id: parseInt(obj.id),
        proceds: [
            ...obj.teams.map(team => ({
                id: team.team_id.toString(),
                proc: object.proceds.find(proc => proc.id == team.team_id).proc
            }))
        ]
    }))
    delete object.proceds;
    return object; 
}

console.log(transform(dados))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to **iterate** each object to make groups.

```js
let dados = {
proceds:[
 {id:'1', proc:'11', teams:[{team_id:1},{team_id:2}]},
 {id:'2', proc:'12', teams:[{team_id:1},{team_id:3}]},
 {id:'3', proc:'13', teams:[{team_id:2},{team_id:3}]},
]
};

const groupByTeams = [];
dados.proceds.forEach(item=> {
  let  {teams, ...teamItems} = item;
teams.forEach(team=>{
groupByTeams.find(x=>x.team_id==team.team_id)?groupByTeams.find(x=>x.team_id==team.team_id).proceds.push({...teamItems}):groupByTeams.push({...team, proceds: [{...teamItems}]});
});
});

console.log({dados:{teams:groupByTeams}});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `reduce` with `Object.keys`

```
const asObject = dados.proceds.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    curr.teams.forEach(t => acc[t.team_id] = [...(acc[t.team_id] || []), { id: curr.id, proc: curr.proc }])
    return acc
}, {})

const result = {
    teams: Object.keys(asObject).map(k => ({ team_id: k, proceds: asObject[k] }))
}
```